# How can I get an Tkinter input from one file to another?

Tags: python, tkinter, local-variables

I am working on a basic hotel management system for my school project. I have made this submit function for a button to log in to a manager. I need to get this local variable ***username*** from this python file *log_in.py* to another python file *dashboard.py*. How shall I do so?

```
def submit():
    username = str(username_entry.get()).strip()
    password = str(password_entry.get()).strip()
    username_exists = username in data.username.values

    employee_id = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT employee_id FROM managers WHERE username = '{username}';", db)
    employee_id = employee_id.employee_id.values[0]
        
    if username_exists: 
        correct_password = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT password FROM managers WHERE username = '{username}';", db)
        correct_password = correct_password.password.values[0]
        password_matches = (password == correct_password)
    
    if not username_exists: messagebox.showerror('Invalid Username', 'The entered username does not exist.')
    elif not password_matches: messagebox.showerror('Invlaid Password', 'The entered password is wrong.')
    else: 
        messagebox.showinfo('Log In Successful', 'You are now logged in.')
        root.destroy()
        os.system('python dashboard.py')
```

Comment: You can pass the `username` as a command line argument to `dashboard.py`: `os.system(f"python dashboard.py {username}")`.  Of course you need to modify `dashboard.py` to read the `username` using `sys.argv`.  However better solution is put the main block of `dashboard.py` in a function that expects `username` as an argument, then import `dashboard` and run this function instead of using `os.system()`.

Comment: Why do you want to start a separate Python process with `os.system()`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you're gonna first have to make the *username* variable global by putting `global username` before declaring the *username* variable:

```
def submit():
    global username
    username = str(username_entry.get()).strip()
    password = str(password_entry.get()).strip()
```

After that, you could import the *username* variable from the *log_in.py* file into the *dashboard.py* file by writing:

```
from log_in import username
```

At the top of *dashboard.py*.

**NOTE: Make sure that both files (log_in.py and dashboard.py) are in the same folder.**

Now, you should have access to the *username* variable ;)

*log_in.py

```
def submit():
    global username
    username = str(username_entry.get()).strip()
    password = str(password_entry.get()).strip()

    #The rest of your code
```

*top of dashboard.py

```
from log_in import username

#The rest of your code
```